# How to find the number of types of buyers for each product per user_id?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I'm working on MySQL workbench 8.0 and I would like to find the number of types of buyers for each product per user_id. For instance, for chairs, if user_id 1, user_id 2, and user_id 3 make purchases only once, I would like to create a column (type of buyer), "BoughtOnce" and add the number of chairs that were purchased; 3 chairs (bought once by each user).

The sample data similar to the original one is shown below.

| user_id | Product |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | chair |
| 1 | bed |
| 2 | bed |
| 1 | chair |
| 3 | bed |
| 2 | sofa |
| 3 | sofa |
| 3 | shelf |
| 2 | chair |

And I would like to find the following result:

| Product | BoughtOnce | BoughtTwice |
| --- | --- | --- |
| chair | 1 | 2 |
| bed | 3 | Null |
| sofa | 2 | Null |
| shelf | 1 | Null |

For instance, user_id 1 bought 2 chairs and user_id 2 bought 1 chair.

I wanted to use the expression below but realized I could not aggregate a window function.

CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT Prodcut) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id) = 1 Then ...

Could anyone help me with this? I'd appreciate your help!

It'd be helpful if you suggest another approach as well.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a functions, it's a _set quantifier_. Simply write `COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)` to make code clearer.

Comment: What's the expected result if someone bought a chair three times?

Comment: I only mentioned one and two-time purchases for demonstration purposes but that might also happen. I'm thinking of adding another column for "BoughtThreeTimes" and "BoughtMoreThanThreeTimes"

Comment: To ``For instance, user_id 1 bought 2 chairs and user_id 2 bought 1 chair`` question is: One(1) user (id=1) bought chair twice. Expected result ``BoughtTwice=2``  - but 1 user bought chair twice. If 3 users bought twice what is expected result? BoughtTwice=6 or 3?

Comment: It's 6. I'm counting the number of chairs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a CTE that gets the number of times one userid gets an item, you then count the occurances of the row_number for a product

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT 
`Product`, ROw_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY `user_id`, `Product`) rn
FROM table1)
SELECT
  `Product`,
SUM(rn = 1) as once,
SUM(rn = 2) as twice,
SUM(rn = 3) as three,
SUM(rn > 3) as morethanthree
FROM CTE
GROUP BY `Product`
```

| Product | once | twice | three | morethanthree |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| bed | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| chair | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| sofa | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| shelf | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/YjJVr89j)

Answer (score 0):

Twice grouping

```
create table test (user_id int,Product varchar(20));
insert into test values
 (1,'chair')
,(1,'bed')
,(2,'bed')
,(1,'chair')
,(3,'bed')
,(2,'sofa')
,(3,'sofa')
,(3,'shelf')
,(2,'chair');
select product
   -- count number of products
  ,sum(case when qty=1 then qty end) BoughtOnce 
  ,sum(case when qty=2 then qty end) BoughtTwice
  ,sum(case when qty>2 then qty end) MoreThanTwice
   -- counted number of buyers
  ,sum(case when qty=1 then 1 end) BoughtOnce   
  ,sum(case when qty=2 then 1 end) BoughtTwice
  ,sum(case when qty>2 then 1 end) MoreThanTwice
from (select product,user_id,count(*) qty
       from test
       group by product,user_id
    ) t
group by product
```

Result

| product | BoughtOnce | BoughtTwice | MoreThanTwice | BoughtOnce | BoughtTwice | MoreThanTwice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| chair | 1 | 2 | null | 1 | 1 | null |
| bed | 3 | null | null | 3 | null | null |
| sofa | 2 | null | null | 2 | null | null |
| shelf | 1 | null | null | 1 | null | null |

[Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/TkhkUFkQ)

Comment: in mysql you don't need case when for summing boolean values

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I had some doubts about this.