# How to find the number of unique_ids based on the number of items purchased

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, aggregate-functions

I asked a similar question on another thread.

[How to find the number of types of buyers for each product per user_id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75859446/how-to-find-the-number-of-types-of-buyers-for-each-product-per-user-id)

I'm working on MySQL workbench 8.0. In this case, I want to find the number of unique user_ids who purchased a product once, twice, more than once, more than twice, etc.

The sample data similar to the original one is shown below.

| user_id | Product |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | chair |
| 1 | chair |
| 3 | chair |
| 4 | chair |
| 1 | chair |
| 2 | chair |
| 4 | table |
| 3 | table |
| 4 | table |
| 3 | table |
| 1 | table |
| 2 | table |
| 5 | table |

The number I want to find is the count of unique_ids. And I would like to find the following result:

| Product | BoughtOnce | BoughtTwice |
| --- | --- | --- |
| chair | 4 | 2 |
| table | 5 | 2 |

For instance, 4 unique people bought only one chair and 2 unique people bought two chairs. Similarly, 5 unique people bought only one table and 2 unique people bought two tables.

From the other thread, I could give row numbers partitioned by user_id and product.

```
SELECT 
user_id, Product, ROw_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY `user_id`, Product) rn
FROM myData;
```

Result:

| user_id | Product | rn |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | chair | 1 |
| 1 | chair | 2 |
| 1 | table | 3 |
| 2 | chair | 1 |
| 2 | chair | 2 |
| 2 | table | 3 |
| 3 | chair | 1 |
| 3 | table | 2 |
| 3 | table | 3 |
| 4 | chair | 1 |
| 4 | table | 2 |
| 4 | table | 3 |
| 5 | table | 1 |

How do I proceed to find the count of unique_ids based on the number of items purchased?

Let me know if you have another approach too.

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with two levels of aggregation: first by user/product, then by product.

```
select product,
    sum(cnt = 1) bought_once,
    sum(cnt = 2) bought_twice
from (
    select product, count(*) cnt
    from mydata 
    group by product, user_id
) d
group by product
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I changed cnt = 1 to cnt >= 1 and found the result I wanted.